# SwiftUI - If inside ForEach loop

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am building a List based on my elements in an array I fetched before.

I am fetching all the entities.. when the user makes a search in the search bar, I want to filter my List. I am NOT doing a new FetchRequest, I just want to filter my objects.

That is the code I am using at the moment:

```
List(selection: $selectedDocument)
{
    ForEach(self.documentItems, id: \.self) { document in
        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            if (self.checkSearchString(document: document))
            {
                ListRow(document: document).tag(document)
            }
    }
```

I am having a List, then my ForEach loop. In that loop, I want to decide if I show that element or not. The problem is, that even if I do not want to show the element, there is still a small view inside my List. I know **why**, it is because I still render that `HStack()`.
I basically need to drag that `HStack()` inside my `If`, however that is not working for me. I think it is because I need to render a view inside my List. But how can I contiuue my `ForEach` without rendering something.

That is what I want to achieve, BUT it is not working:

```
 List(selection: $selectedDocument)
 {
     ForEach(self.documentItems, id: \.self) { document in
         if (self.checkSearchString(document: document))
         {
             HStack(spacing: 0)
             {
                 ListRow(document: document).tag(document)
             }
         }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

filter your data BEFORE passing it to ForEach constuctor.

```
ForEach(self.documentItems.filter {self.checkSearchString(document: $0)}, id: \.self) { document in
    HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            ListRow(document: document).tag(document)
        }
}
```

Comment: This is what Apple recommends as well, source WWDC 23 session Demystify SwiftUI performance: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10160?time=951 
When inside of a List or Table they advise filtering the collection before passing it into the ForEach instead of having an if statement inside the ForEach because it keeps the number of views in the ForEach constant. Using the if statement "results in list needing to build all the views to retrieve the row identifiers because it doesn't know how many views each element resolves to."

Answer (score 13):

You need to use `Group` to wrap different views provided by condition, like below

```
 ForEach(self.documentItems, id: \.self) { document in
   Group {
     if (self.checkSearchString(document: document))
     {
         HStack(spacing: 0)
         {
             ListRow(document: document).tag(document)
         }
     }
     else 
     {
        EmptyView()
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does returning an EmptyView() hide the ForEach item?

Answer (score 0):

```
List(selection: $selectedDocument)
{
    ForEach(self.documentItems, id: \.self) { document in

       self.checkSearchString(document: document) ?  extractedHstack() : emptyView()

    }
```

Extract your hstack and use a trinary with an empty view. Let me know if this works I did this from memory no IDE on this computer.

Comment: We tried that.. it works when we use it like that                     self.checkSearchString(document: document) ? EmptyView() : EmptyView()
But if we replace the first EmptyView() with our view, it is not working anymore